# What would happen if I press "Refresh Tor Browser" on about:support page?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, tor-button

What would happen if I press "Refresh Tor Browser" on about:support page?

Would the bundled extensions (like Torbutton) be gone too and become standard Firefox browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes (I once tried it), so **DO NOT DO THAT**! It will completely remove everything, including Torbutton.

If you want a clean fresh re-install of the Tor Browser just download it again from the official site (http**s**://torproject.org) and delete the previous copy of the Tor Browser and install it again.

Comment: It seems the Tor Browser programmers not able to modify Firefox codebase related to about:support.

Comment: Right, part of the "refresh" process firefox goes through is to remove extensions/addons and since Tor Browser relies of a few addons, they would be stripped causing it to fail.

Comment: This would be https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/10760